# Python inheritance: convert from Base class to Derived class

Tags: python, inheritance

I'm still pretty new to Python, so bear with me.  Here is my problem:

I have a base class, lets call it a sports game:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.home_team = None
        self.away_team = None
```

and I have multiple derived classes for each sport, but lets use baseball as an example:

```
class BaseballGame(Game):
    def __init__(self):
        self.home_pitcher = None
        self.away_pitcher = None
```

So far everything is good.  However I have another utility function in a separate python module which will generate and populate a list of all the games being played on a given day for that sport.

```
def fetch_game_data:
    games = []
    games_found_online = code_that_fetches_online_games
    for online_game in games_found_online:
        new_game = Game()
        new_game.home_team = ...
        new_game.away_team = ...
        games.append(new_game)
    return games
```

Its obviously much more complicated than this with a lot of parsing using BeautifulSoup, but you get the point.  My problem is that this function returns a list of the Base class, but I need a list of the Derived class.  The derived classes will be the ones calling this function to populate a list and operate on it.  The way I see it, I have two options:

1. I could implement a dreaded circular dependency and have the fetch_game_data function know about all of the derived classes and call the derived class constructors instead of the base class constructors.  The derived classes already need to import the fetch_data module, but now the fetch_data module will have to import all of the derived classes to know about their constructors.  And what makes it worse is that the fetch_data module won't have any need to touch any of the derived class fields - it only populates base class fields.  The circular dependency is JUST so I can create the objects.

   2. I could implement code that downcasts a Base class Game to a Derived class Game (like BaseballGame).  Then, when the fetch_game_data function returns all of the games I can just convert them all to a Derived class object and continue on my way.  Unfortunately I haven't seen much in the way of how to implement this.  I tried just changing the **class** variable, but then the code complains because Derived class variables don't exist.

Another option I considered, but quickly fell apart, was to send an existing list of derived class objects into the fetch_game_data function, and instead of creating new Game objects it would just populate existing ones.  The problem is that I won't know how many game objects I need.  The fetch_game_data function determines how many games are needed by parsing the webpage.  I suppose I could send in the max number of games but using number_of_teams/2, but what if there is a double-header in baseball?  This quickly falls apart.  I suppose I could write a function that will fetch the game data and just return the number of games for the day.  Then I could populate a list of Derived games that size and send it in to be populated.  But I would have to fetch all the webpage data AGAIN and parse it AGAIN to populate the list.

Nothing but bad options!  I'm hoping there is a simple and elegant solution that has just eluded me thus far.  I'm open to any suggestions, including a redesign if it makes sense.

Thanks!

Comment: What about Factory class, like in a Factory pattern?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Python cannot cast an object to another class (even subclass).

You must use concrete class when you create the game object. It can be done in a factory method (e.g. `create_game`), like this:

```
def create_game(online_game):
    if online_game.type == 'baseball':
        return BaseballGame()
    else:
        return Game()

def fetch_game_data:
    games = []
    games_found_online = code_that_fetches_online_games
    for online_game in games_found_online:
        new_game = create_game(online_game)
        new_game.home_team = ...
        new_game.away_team = ...
        games.append(new_game)
    return games
```

Comment: *Python cannot cast an object to another class (even subclass).* -- of course it can, indirectly via copying an instance's dict or directly through changing an instances `.__class__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a class of instance after it is initiated, see example below:

```py
class A:
    def __repr__(self):
        return "class A"
    def convert(self):
        'convert A to B class'
        self.__class__ = B
    def hello(self):
        print('hello from A')
        
        
class B(A):
    ""
    def __repr__(self):
        return "class B"
            
    def hello(self):
        print('hello from B')
        

a = A()

print(a)
a.hello()
a.convert()
print(a)
a.hello()
```

```
# output:
>>> "class A"
>>> "hello from A"
>>> "class B"
>>> "hello from B"
```

In your case, you can convert the class `Game` to whatever subclass you want after the instance is created.

Answer (score 0):

I am porting existing code from c++ and I encountered a similar problem.

I have a generic class X and type specific classes e.g. XInt, XStr etc. There is more differences between these classes than just the type of the value. In c++ it was easy: I have `virtual X::compare(X const& other)`.

It is overridden in XInt. Inside the overridden method I first handle cases where the 'other' is not XInt and then do `static_cast<XInt const&>(other)`.

It is clearly impossible in python. So here is my solution. I added a non-virtual non-public function to do actual comparison to XInt and did not annotate the type of the parameter:

```
def _compare(self, other) -> int:
     <do-actual-comparison>

def compare(self, other: X) -> int:
     <handle cases where other is not XInt>
     return self._compare_worker(other)
```

Did not test it yet but mypy does not complain and it seems that it will work due to duck typing in python. Maybe something similar will work for you.